# How to get specified data from the table column using where clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've a table having the columns like

```
         Prefix                     CModel

          g                     ;#WR_1;#WR_2;#WR_3;#WR_4;# 

          v                  ;#WR_3;#WR_4;#

         j                     WR_2

         m                     WR_1

         d              ;#WR_3;#WR_4;#   

          f9                      WR_3
```

I want to retrieve data from all columns WHERE CModel=WR_3 from CModel.

```
SELECT Prefix,CModel From table1 WHERE CModel = WR_3;
```

It returns only one row.

```
                Prefix      CMODEL

                f9        WR_3
```

i want it to be return 4 rows since WR_3 exists in 4 rows(contains colon delimted like ;#WR_3;#WR_4;#).How to specify that in WHERE Condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your table structure, I would use something like this:

```
SELECT Prefix, CModel
FROM table1
WHERE
  [CModel] IS NOT NULL
  AND (";" & Replace([CModel], "#", "") & ";") Like "*;WR_3;*";
```

- `Replace([CModel], "#", "")` will remove all `#` characters from the model
- `";" & Replace(...) & ";"` will add one ; at the beginning and one ; at the end of the string
- `Like "*;WR_3;*"` will match all strings that contain `;WR_3;` so it will also match rows that contain just `WR_3` but it won't match rows that contain `WR_30`

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply .It says Data type Mismatch in criteria expression.Though CModel field is Text field.

Comment: @swa1234 what type is cmodel?

Comment: @swa1234 can you try to select `SELECT table1.Prefix, (";" & Replace([CModel],"#","") & ";") FROM table1;` ? does it work?

Comment: It works but where do i need to specify **WR_3** in **SELECT** statement? And 'Null' value columns returns **#Error**.

Comment: @swa1234 okay the problem is probably with null columns, and since they won't match anyway we can just skip null values... please see my updated answer

Comment: How can i retrive null values too